# `The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete.` error when I use ML.NET Model Builder

Tags: json-rpc, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I am using .NET Model Builder to use ML.NET Text Classification. And whenever I click train, later it gives me an error saying `The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete`. I looked through different websites and updated Visual Studio to the latest version (17.8.3) and even repaired but still didn't work.

I saw this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1327986/how-to-fix-streamjsonrpc-connectionlostexception-t) and renamed `ComponentModelCache` file to `ComponentModelCache.old` and used `devenv /ResetSettings` command in Developer Command Prompt For Visual Studio 2022 but still didn't work at all. When I opened the log, it seems like the environment paths are correct and the ML.NET Model Builder is able to begin the training process, but it seems to lose the JSON-RPC connection during the operation. The network is very stable so that is not an issue as well. When I researched, it seems like quite a few people are experiencing the same error but it's on Visual Studio. For me, VS works completely fine but whenever I run ML.NET Text Classification, it gives me the error.

Is there anything I can do again to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: I have this same problem and cannot fix it.